# Problema con variable para llamado de funcion

Tags: c++

Tengo la varible hojaInicial y hojaFinal donde realizo el proceso de llenar la hojaInicial y luego pongo hojaFinal como un arreglo dinamico :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int nfilas, ncolumnas;
char ***hojaInicial;
int **hojaFinal;

cout << "Ingrese cantidad de filas y columnas: ";
cin >> nfilas >> ncolumnas;

cin.ignore();

for (int i = 0; i < nfilas; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ncolumnas; j++) {
        cin.getline(*(*(hojaInicial + i) + j), 10);
    }
}

hojaFinal = new int *[nfilas];
cout << "Hoja final: \n\n";
for (int i = 0; i < nfilas; i++) {
    *(hojaFinal + i) = new int[ncolumnas];
}
calcularHoja(hojaInicial,nfilas,ncolumnas,hojaFinal);
}
```

Resulta que luego tengo este llamado a una funcion:

```
calcularHoja(hojaInicial,nfilas,ncolumnas,hojaFinal);
```

Y la funcion en cuestion es:

```
void calcularHoja(char*** hojaInicial, int nfilas,int ncolumnas, int **hojaFinal){
int fil,col,suma;
    char *celda;
    for(int i=0;i<nfilas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<ncolumnas;j++){
            if(*(*(*(hojaInicial+i)+j)) != '='){
                *(*(hojaFinal+i)+j)=atoi(*(*(hojaInicial+i)+j));
                cout<<*(*(hojaFinal+i)+j)<<"\t";
            }
            else{
                suma=0;
                celda=strtok(*(*(hojaInicial+i)+j),"+=");
                while(celda != NULL)
                    {
                    if((*celda>= 'A')&&(*celda<='Z')){
                        col=int(*celda)-65;
                        celda++;
                        fil=atoi(celda)-1;
                        suma=suma+(*(*(hojaFinal+fil)+col));
                        celda=strtok(NULL,"+=");
                    }
                    else{
                        suma=suma+atoi(celda);
                        celda=strtok(NULL,"+=");
                    }
                }
                *(*(hojaFinal+i)+j)=suma;
                cout<<*(*(hojaFinal+i)+j)<<"\t";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

De aqui solo me interesa la variable hojaInicial pues es la que me da problemas a la hora de llamar la funcion, de la forma que muestro aca el programa me compila pero se cierra cuando introduzco los datos de fila y columna y no me deja ingresar los valores para cada celda y si declaro la variable de de la forma:

```
char hojaInicial[5][5][10];
```

No me compila y me da este error:

```
error: cannot convert 'char (*)[5][10]' to 'char***'
```

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias

Comment: En el primer caso (declarar char***) estás intentando usar cin sobre memoria no inicializada. No podés declarar un puntero y usarlo para leer datos porque no apunta a ningún lado (ie: la dirección que tiene es restos de la memoria o null). No me asombraría ver un core dump. En el segundo caso podés resolverlo casteando a (char***) o cambiando la declaración de la función. Hay errores conceptuales en el código. Me gustaría que cambies el post y publiques el código completo (includes, función y main) para ofrecerte una respuesta completa que les sirva a otros. Saludos.

Comment: @D4RIO ya acabo de poner completo el codigo, puse la funcion calcularHoja completa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Declarando como `char***` el programa se cierra

Al declarar hojaInicial como `char***`, el compilador únicamente sabe
que es un puntero, que apunta a otro puntero, que apunta a una cadena
del tipo `char*`, algo que debería representar a un vector, de vectores,
de cadenas, pero ni los vectores, ni las cadenas tienen la memoria
reservada en la declaración. Algo así debe ser:

```
  [hojaInicial] << Este es el único que existe al declarar (char***).
   |
   | << Apunta a un vector, en este caso el # de filas es 3.
   |    Cada uno de estos del 1 al 3 es un char**, porque apunta
   |    a un char*.
   V
  [1] --> [a][b][c][d]
  [2] --> [e][f][g][h]
  [3] --> [i][j][k][l]

          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
          El vector de la izquierda tiene punteros al inicio de estos
          3 vectores (3 filas). En este caso las columnas son 4.
          Cada valor de la 'a' a la 'l' es a su vez un puntero a una
          cadena de 10 carácteres. Si declarásemos 'a', sería char *a
          y habría que asignar con new char[10].
```

Otra vez, al declarar `char***` únicamente se declara un puntero, que tiene
la intención de apuntar al primero de una serie de punteros, que tienen la
intención de apuntar al primero de una serie de `char*`, o sea cadenas
representadas por un puntero al primer elemento. Esto es más complicado de
leer que de dibujar y entender.

Al asignar memoria, estamos dandole dimensión a toda la estructura a la
que debe apuntar `hojaInicial`, lo mismo que sucede más abajo con
`hojaFinal`.

## Declarando como `char hojaInicial[5][5][10]` da error de compilación

En realidad esto se puede resolver declarando la función como:

```cpp
void calcularHoja(char hojaInicial[5][5][10], int nfilas,int ncolumnas, int **hojaFinal)
```

o también casteando la llamada:

```cpp
calcularHoja((char***)hojaInicial,nfilas,ncolumnas,hojaFinal);
```

Pero hay un problema mayor y es que el número de filas y columnas se lee, y no es fijo en 5x5. Por este motivo cualquiera de estas es una mala idea.

## Aritmética de punteros

Tener en cuenta que:

- `*(variable+i)` es lo mismo que `variable[i]`
- `*(*(variable+1))` es lo mismo que `variable[i][0]`
- `*(*(variable+i)+j)` es lo mismo que `variable[i][j]`

En los tres casos la segunda forma es mucho más simple de ver.

## Solución

Lo que necesitas hacer es declarar como `char***` y asignar la memoria. Esta solución contiene las mejoras mencionadas antes. No libera la memoria asignada con `new` (algo que deberías agregar). El código con los estados anteriores y parte del post en los mensajes de commit está en mi [GitHub](https://github.com/D4RIO/stackov-479537):

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

void calcularHoja(char*** hojaInicial, int nfilas,int ncolumnas, int **hojaFinal)
{
    int fil,col,suma;
    char *celda;
    for(int i=0;i<nfilas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<ncolumnas;j++){
            if(hojaInicial[i][j][0] != '='){
                hojaFinal[i][j]=atoi(hojaInicial[i][j]);
                cout<<hojaFinal[i][j]<<"\t";
            }
            else{
                suma=0;
                celda=strtok(hojaInicial[i][j],"+=");
                while(celda != NULL)
                {
                    if((celda[0]>= 'A')&&(celda[0]<='Z')){
                        col=int(celda[0])-65;
                        celda++;
                        fil=atoi(celda)-1;
                        suma=suma+(hojaFinal[fil][col]);
                        celda=strtok(NULL,"+=");
                    }
                    else{
                        suma=suma+atoi(celda);
                        celda=strtok(NULL,"+=");
                    }
                }
                hojaFinal[i][j]=suma;
                cout<<hojaFinal[i][j]<<"\t";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int nfilas, ncolumnas;
    char ***hojaInicial;
    int **hojaFinal;

    cout << "Ingrese cantidad de filas y columnas: ";
    cin >> nfilas >> ncolumnas;

    cin.ignore();

    hojaInicial = new char**[nfilas];
    for (int i = 0; i < nfilas; i++) {
        hojaInicial[i] = new char*[ncolumnas];
        for (int j = 0; j < ncolumnas; j++) {
            hojaInicial[i][j] = new char[10];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nfilas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncolumnas; j++) {
            cout << i << "," << j << ": ";
            cin.getline(hojaInicial[i][j], 10);
        }
    }

    hojaFinal = new int *[nfilas];
    cout << "Hoja final: \n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < nfilas; i++) {
        hojaFinal[i] = new int[ncolumnas];
    }
    calcularHoja(hojaInicial,nfilas,ncolumnas,hojaFinal);
}
```

Un saludo.